# How to get data such as Heart Rate and Pedometer from Samsung Health to Tizen Application?

Tags: web-applications, tizen, nativeapplication, samsung-health

I am currently trying to develop a Tizen Application using Tizen Studio that retrieves data such as Heart Rate, Sleep Monitor, and Pedometer from Samsung Health application(from the smart watch).

Is it possible to retrieve this data? If not what are the possible ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is using SHealth SDK via Android application. (https://developer.samsung.com/health). The main problem starts here, you need to have a partnership with Samsung Health to publish the app.

There's no other solution btw. You can try to get data from sensors directly, but then your values will differ from SHealth and not easy to maintain.