# Sensor recorder time period doesn't follow query settings

Tags: tizen-native-app

I am trying to use the PEDOMETER on Tizen wearable 5.5. I can get the sensor listener to work and return the data. But the data is aggregated to something I can't find documentation about.
So then I found that I need to do the calculation of steps myself (and found a few samples in the Tizen forum and GitHub) but the behavior I am getting when using the recorder is quite weird.

I am running this on my Samsung Watch, not in the emulator.

Here is my code:

```
void get_initial_pedometer_data() {

  // Check the sensor recorder is supported
  bool recorderSupported;
  sensor_recorder_is_supported(SENSOR_HUMAN_PEDOMETER, &recorderSupported);
  if (!recorderSupported) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Recorder not supported.");
    return;
  }

  // Create the sensor recorder and query
  sensor_recorder_create_option(&option);
  sensor_recorder_option_set_int(option, SENSOR_RECORDER_OPTION_RETENTION_PERIOD, 24);
  sensor_recorder_start(SENSOR_HUMAN_PEDOMETER, option);
  sensor_recorder_query_h query;
  if (sensor_recorder_create_query(&query) != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Cannot create query");
    return;
  }

  // Calculate and set the FROM/TO times for the query
  time_t nowTime, startTime;
  nowTime = time(NULL);
  struct tm *tmNow = localtime(&nowTime);
  dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Query end time [%ld]: %d %dh%dm%ds",
            nowTime, tmNow->tm_mday, tmNow->tm_hour, tmNow->tm_min,
            tmNow->tm_sec);

  startTime = nowTime - (tmNow->tm_hour * 3600) - (tmNow->tm_min * 60)
            - (tmNow->tm_sec);

  struct tm *tmStart = localtime(&startTime);
  dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Query start time [%ld]: %d %dh%dm%ds",
            startTime, tmStart->tm_mday, tmStart->tm_hour, tmStart->tm_min,
            tmStart->tm_sec);

  if (sensor_recorder_query_set_time(query, SENSOR_RECORDER_QUERY_START_TIME, startTime) != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Cannot set query START option: %ld.", startTime);
    return;
  }
  if (sensor_recorder_query_set_time(query, SENSOR_RECORDER_QUERY_END_TIME, nowTime) != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Cannot set query END option: %ld.", nowTime);
    return;
  }
  if (sensor_recorder_query_set_int(query, SENSOR_RECORDER_QUERY_TIME_INTERVAL, 24 * 60) != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Cannot set query INTERVAL option: %d.", 24 * 60);
    return;
  }

  if (sensor_recorder_query_set_time(query, SENSOR_RECORDER_QUERY_ANCHOR_TIME, startTime) != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Cannot set query ANCHOR option: %ld.", startTime);
    return;
  }

  // Query the data
  int error = sensor_recorder_read_sync(SENSOR_HUMAN_PEDOMETER, query, sensor_pedometer_data_cb, NULL);
  if (error != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Cannot read query: %d", error);
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have fixed the code above with the correct values to query from 0.00 to current time.

Then the callback method is:

```
bool sensor_pedometer_data_cb(sensor_type_e type, sensor_recorder_data_h data, int remains, sensor_error_e error, void *user_data) {
  if (type != SENSOR_HUMAN_PEDOMETER) {
    return true;
  }

  if (error != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Sensor record callback error: %d", error);
    return true;
  }

  int step;
  time_t start;
  time_t end;

  // Get the data
  sensor_recorder_data_get_time(data, &start, &end);
  struct tm *tmStart = localtime(&start);

  // Print the START/END time
  dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Start time: %d %d:%d:%d", tmStart->tm_mday, tmStart->tm_hour, tmStart->tm_min, tmStart->tm_sec);
  struct tm *tmEnd = localtime(&end);
  dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "End time: %d %d:%d:%d", tmEnd->tm_mday, tmEnd->tm_hour, tmEnd->tm_min, tmEnd->tm_sec);

  sensor_recorder_data_get_int(data, SENSOR_RECORDER_DATA_STEPS, &step);
  step_count += step;
  if (remains == 0) {
    total_steps = step_count;
    step_count = 0;
    int error = sensor_listener_start(listener);
    if (error != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, "Cannot start listener. Error: %d", error);
    }
  }
  dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Step count: %d", total_steps);
  return true;
}
```

Now with the recorded data and the sensor data, I can't find how to calculate the number of step for the current day. Is there any document that can explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more helpful to share more of the results of using this code(such as your logs).

This API seems to design for long-term records. Did you refer to this document?
Briefly, It seems like a way to request a long-term record of the sensor and then query it later to get the data.

- https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/location-sensors/device-sensors/#record

and you would better use SHealth SDK to get step count history on the Galaxy watch
see: [How to get data such as Heart Rate and Pedometer from Samsung Health to Tizen Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560562/how-to-get-data-such-as-heart-rate-and-pedometer-from-samsung-health-to-tizen-ap)

Comment: I think I was using this document on Tizen docs, but with a fresh new read (didn't get back to this project for 2 months) I see I can try update correctly using the long term data-recording. I'm +1 for now, and will mark the answer as valid if I can solve it that way.

Comment: Got it to work using the long-term data recording. I guess I wasn't looking correctly first time. Thank you again!